# Using Facebook social plugin "like" button in Yahoo Site Builder

Tags: facebook-like, yahoo, facebook-social-plugins

How do I get the iframe code to work on my website built using Yahoo's Site Builder?  It will not accept the Java code in either HTML or the other format without erasing my background.

Comment: Its up to Yahoo to decide what they let in.  This is not a facebook issue.

Comment: took me only 30 seconds to find these answers, to help support the growth and use of facebook plugins on yahoo @Lix

Comment: the tags on this question show it is a facebook related question - this is not.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a very easy way to do so. It's as simple as copy some html and paste. I use Yahoo Sitebuilder frequently and this stumped me for a bit as well but I did [find the answer](http://sitebuilder.djxtech-music.com/page2.html).

When you go onto this next site, and I'll link it. 
You can either sign on with your Facebook 
account or register a new account with them. The 
registration is really simple because it's really just 
a 3 question form and you'll be on your way.

1. Go to [ADDTHIS.com](http://www.addthis.com/) and register.
2. Once you have completed the registration, 
   create the buttons that you want to add and 
   implement them as HTML on your site.

should take you less than 2 minutes to add the like button as well as share buttons for other networks like G+.